# Xpath to extract elements from nodes based on element condition

Tags: java, xml, xpath, tags, nodes

I have an xml for extracting elements -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Carmodels>
  <Cars>
    <id>1223</id>
    <cartype>Sedan</cartype>
    <price>1000</price>
  </Cars>
  <Cars>
    <id>1234</id>
    <car>Sports</car>
    <price>2500</price>
  </Cars>
  <Cars>
    <id>1123</id>
    <car>Taxi</car>
    <price>9000</price>
  </Cars>
  <Cars>
   <id>1223</id>
    <car>Taxi</car>
    <price>1000</price>
   </Cars>
</Carmodels>
```

Now I would need to extract `<price>` tags from `<cars>` node where `<car>` = Taxi. I need only **Xpath** for extracting the price.

Sample output:

```
 9000
 1000
```

We need Xpath only to execute through Java.

Comment: Show how did you try

Comment: Maybe `//Cars[car="Taxi"]/price`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following XPath expression. It converts the **car** tag value to lower case. So both *Taxi* and *taxi* are taken into account.

**XPath**

```
/Carmodels/Cars[lower-case(car)="taxi"]/price
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 expressions which supports the word taxi written with lowercase or uppercase characters :

```
//Cars[car[translate(.,"tT","tt")="taxi"]]/price
//car[translate(.,"tT","tt")="taxi"]/following-sibling::price
```

Output : 2 nodes

```
<price>9000</price>
<price>1000</price>
```